# Specify multiple symbols to exclude from VS2010 debugging session

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, symbols

I know how to use the VS2010 "Specify excluded modules" feature to do just that, specify one module to exclude from your debugging session.  But how do I specify more than one symbol?  Doing one at a time is quite tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out, two solutions:

1)  Using Process Monitor, found that these are saved to DOCS_PATH\Visual Studio 2010\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings.  Under the `<PropertyValue name="SymbolExcludeList">` enter the semicolon delimited list here, restart VS.

2)  The easy way, you can paste in the semicolon delimited list on one line item on the "Symbols to exclude from automatic loading" dialog, it will then add the multiple items as desired.